Old English(?) Movie With Ninjas
I'm searching for a old movie (I saw it in the late 80s in Portugal, so it should be from early 70s to mid 80s) that had several ninjas.
The protagonist was dressed in white, and there were at least 5 enemy ninjas. The one dressed in yellow didn't seem to have any distinct abilities, but I remember a blue one using ice "magic", a red one using fire "magic", a dark green one controlling earth and trees and the black one, that was the final villain, was capable of becoming invisible.
I remember the last fight being in a beach, the fight with the green ninja (the penultimate fight) in some woods, and either the red or blue ninja (or both) being fought during the night. I think the yellow ninja was fought inside a regular japanese house.
I rented the movie and I think it was (at least) English dubbed with portuguese subtitles, but it could be a Japanese movie.

Sounds just like Mortal Kombat, but this movie is from the 90s.

Have you find it?
I also remember this movie and I think the Portuguese title was "Esquadrão Ninja" or something like that (Ninja Squad) but I cant find it.

Try The Super Ninja. In portuguese Esquadrão Ninja

"5 Element Ninjas"(Hong Kong;1982)? 
Directed by Chang Cheh, it has 5 different ninjas representing 5 elements, which are wood, earth, gold, water and fire. The protagonist was dressed in white, but this is common in Chinese kung-fu flicks. Here is a trailer from Youtube.




The trailer seems familiar, I'll have to check it in more detail.

Could be Enter The Ninja (1981)?




hmmm. have to try and see more of it. From what the movie trailer shows, I don't see much of what I remember, but it may just be a case of the trailer just not having things I remember...

searched for more information on the movie and it seems it's not this one. It doesn't have any kind of magic or other special abilities. But from what I've read, there are more movies in this "universe", still have to check those.
